# Create a Zip File in Memory ios swift?

Tags: ios, swift, encryption, zip

We have stored image as an encrypted format and stored in local path. And once we captured the all documents the user click on submit button on that scenario we have decrypted all the images using **RNCryptor**(https://github.com/RNCryptor/RNCryptor) and save as **Zip** and https://github.com/marmelroy/Zip

But we have to store a decrypt format in memory instead of disk.

**How would I zip a file so I could send it without writing to the hard drive and do it purely in memory?**

Comment: I can't think of a use case where the overhead of "saving to disk before sending" would be too much. Even if you somehow achieve the first part (zip and keep in memory), you'll need it saved for the next part (send it). I would recommend storing it in temp directory

Comment: Can you explain how the first part could be achieved?

Comment: How'd it work out? If it was not helpful, let me know where you got stuck.

Comment: Hi Tommie, I have a question regarding zipping. Is it possible to create a zip in memory to store multiple images instead of creating in the disk to store images? If yes please give me an idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Update

Another alternative is the [ZIPFoundation](https://github.com/weichsel/ZIPFoundation) library on Github (MIT/Thomas Zoechling). It appears to be Swift compatible and is apparently "effortless." BTW - I learned about this library while reading an interesting [blog article](https://desiatov.com/swift-codable-xlsx/) where the author (Max Desiatov) walks through how he unzips in memory using the library (see the section - *Unzipping an archive in memory and parsing the contents*).

### Original

Have you taken a close look at the Single-Step Compression [article](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/compression/compressing_and_decompressing_data_with_buffer_compression#)? There is a section that talks about writing the compressed data to file (but it's already been compressed in memory at that point). Once you get the data generated then I guess you could do with it as you will...

### Article Steps

1. Create the Source Data
2. Create the Destination Buffer
3. Select a Compression Algorithm
4. **Compress the Data**
5. Write the Encoded Data to a File
6. Read the Encoded Data from a File
7. Decompress the Data

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Tommie. I will try and let you know.